# Why does removing a small number of large files take a long time?

Tags: linux, filesystems

On my external hard disk, with an ext3 filesystem, I removed 6 files of 7.2 GB each.  Removing those (`rm *`) took surprisingly long, a minute or so.  As it should only need to unlink the file entries from the filesystem, why should it take longer to delete a small number of large files than it does to delete a small number of small files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deleting a file, the ext3 filesystem will actually [zero out the block pointers](http://batleth.sapienti-sat.org/projects/FAQs/ext3-faq.html#undelete) in the [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode_pointer_structure). The larger the file, the more blocks, and the more block pointers, thus the delete operation takes longer on larger files than smaller ones.

This is different behavior than both ext2, which merely zeroes out the inode and leaves the blocks containing the block pointers intact (but marked as free) and ext4, which uses [extents](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2010/12/20/digital-forensics-understanding-ext4-part-1-extents) (and, since extents are a much more compact structure, has much better delete performance, that slows down based on how fragmented the file is, rather than how big it is).